# sending multiple parameters from form to report query

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

Trying to send three variables (startDate, endDate, division) from a chooser form to a report query.  Sent the three variables through an doCommand.OpenReport command, then unpacked them in the Load event of the report.  I'm not sure what to assign them to in the report to use them in the query.

In the form:

```
Private Sub btn_bud_sum_exp_div_Click()
    Dim StrWhereCondition
    Dim a As String
    Dim b As String
    Dim c As String

    a = Me.txtStartDate.Value
    b = Me.txtEndDate.Value
    c = Me.lstDivision.Value

    StrWhereCondition = a & "|" & b & "|" & c

    'StrWhereCondition = "[accounting start date] = " & Me.txtStartDate.Text

    DoCmd.OpenReport "FY15 Budget Line Sum - Expenditures - Div", , ,    StrWhereCondition
End Sub
```

In the Load event of the report:

```
Private Sub Report_Load()
    Dim dtStartDate As Date
    Dim dtEndDate As Date
    Dim strDivision As String

    If Not IsNull(Me.OpenArgs) Then
        dtStartDate = parsetext(OpenArgs, 0)
        dtEndDate = parsetext(OpenArgs, 1)
        strDivision = parsetext(OpenArgs, 2)
    End If
End Sub
```

In the report query:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    budget b
WHERE 
    (b.start_date between dtStartDate AND dtEndDate) AND d.division = strDivision
```

Comment: Your parameters should be in the query, not the report as a parameter (a filter maybe?). You can have the query reference them from the form used to call the report.  WHERE [dtStartDate] = FORMS![YOURFORM]!txtStartDate

Comment: What is the datatype of your `budget.division` field?

Answer (score 0):

If you open the report with a filter string, you can delete all the OnLoad stuff of the report:

```
Private Sub btn_bud_sum_exp_div_Click()

    Dim StartDate      As String
    Dim EndDate        As String
    Dim Division       As String
    Dim WhereCondition As String

    StartDate = Format(Me!txtStartDate.Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd")
    EndDate = Format(Me!txtEndDate.Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd")
    Division = Me!lstDivision.Value

    WhereCondition = "start_date between #" & StartDate & "# and #" & EndDate & "# and division = " & Division & ""
    ' or:
    ' WhereCondition = "[accounting start date] between #" & StartDate & "# and #" & EndDate & "# and division = " & Division & ""
    ' or, if division is text:
    ' WhereCondition = "start_date between #" & StartDate & "# and #" & EndDate & "# and division = '" & Division & "'"

    DoCmd.OpenReport "FY15 Budget Line Sum - Expenditures - Div", , , WhereCondition

End Sub
```